# Is there a function similar to std::lower_bound without needing a sorted/partitioned input?

Tags: c++, find, lower-bound

Is there a STL function that returns an iterator or index to the smallest element greater than some input value in an unsorted array. `std::lower_bound` doesn't work because it requires partitioning, and my array is not partitioned according to its requirements.

For example,

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   vector<int> vec{5,1,2,9,1,5,3};

   std::cout << std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2) - vec.begin() << std::endl;
}
```

The output here is 3 when I want it to be 6 corresponding to vec[6].

Comment: "*smallest first*": Do you just mean "*smallest*", or "*first smallest*"? Also you are writing "*greater than*", but `vec[6]` is *equal* to `3`.

Comment: "smallest first"? What shall that be? You mean "first smallest"? Or just "smallest"?

Comment: @walnut. I'm having trouble with the semantics. What's the difference between the 3? I want find the element `vec[i]` such that `vec[i] > input val` and `vec[i]` is as small as possible.

Comment: How should the function return 6? That does not match your requirements given in the question's text.

Comment: @Werner I reworded it in the OP just now. I think what I'm describing corresponds to "smallest."

Comment: `std::min_element` with a suitable comparison predicate could do it (basically, treat all elements smaller than a given threshold as "positive infinity" - compared larger than anything else). Though at this point it's probably easiest to write your own function, with a simple loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you actually do that with `min_element`? I don't think we can satisfy **strict** weak ordering with this approach.

Comment: @Timo Why not? Strict weak ordering doesn't preclude a class of equivalent values that compare greater than all others. Which requirement, specifically, do you believe that would violate?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how would you handle the case where both `a` and `b` are lower than the threshold? I think we can't satisfy commutativity.

Comment: @Timo I would say that neither compares smaller than the other, thus making them equivalent.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik nvm I've seen the asnwer.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't such an STL algorithm. You can find a list of all of them [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm). Having said that, it's possible to implement such a function by abusing `min_element`:

```
template <typename ForwardIt, typename Value>
ForwardIt unsortedLowerBound(ForwardIt const beg, ForwardIt const end,
                             Value const& val) {
  auto result =
      std::min_element(beg, end, [&val](auto const& e1, auto const& e2) {
        if (e1 <= val) return false;
        if (e2 <= val) return true;
        return e1 < e2;
      });
  if (result != end && *result <= val) result = end;
  return result;
}
```

---

Additionally note that you must test with `end` to see if there is any item that satisfies the requirement.